# Implementing a custom string method

Tags: python

How do you add a custom method to a built-in python datatype?  For example, I'd like to implement one of the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/the-shortest-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string-in-python) but be able to call it as follows:

```
>>> s = "A   string  with extra   whitespace"
>>> print s.strip_inner()
>>> A string with extra whitespace
```

So how would I define a custom `.strip_inner()` string method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending builtin classes in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352537/extending-builtin-classes-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. And you don't need to.

See [Extending builtin classes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352537/extending-builtin-classes-in-python) for an alternative solution. Subclassing is the way to go here.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't want to.  I wanted to subclass I just couldn't remember what it was called so I couldn't google the solution myself.  Thanks.

Comment: On closer inspection that is not exactly what I was trying to do (as you say, I can't do *exactly* what I want), but it is certainly a workable solution.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in classes such as `str` are implemented in C, so you can't manipulate them. What you can do, instead, is extend the `str` class:

```
>>> class my_str(str):
...     def strip_inner(self):
...         return re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', s)
... 
>>> s = my_str("A   string  with extra   whitespace")
>>> print s.strip_inner()
A string with extra whitespace
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add methods to built-in classes. But what's wrong with using functions? `strip_inner(s)` is just fine and pythonic.

If you need polymorphism, then just use `if isinstance(obj, type_)` to determine what to do, or for something more extensible, use a generic function package, like [PEAK-Rules](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PEAK-Rules).

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph and -1 for the second one. As to why function may be better than method see [methods vs. functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967538/)