# Python defining Function

Tags: python, string, function

I want to make a function that strips whitespace from a string, what I have so far is:

```
def stripped(x):
    x = x.replace('  ', '')

string = " yes   Maybe   So"
```

I want to just strip the space by doing this

```
string.stripped()
```

but I keep getting this error 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'stripped'

what am I doing wrong I am guessing it is something simple I am just overlooking, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give the string to `stripped`. `stripped` isn't a string method.

Comment: you want `stripped` to `return x` and then `string = stripped(string)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing a custom string method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519702/implementing-a-custom-string-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your function, you Python creates a lone function object called `stripped`. It doesn't add your function to the builtin `str` object. You just

```
need to call your method on the string normally:

>>> def stripped(x):
    x = x.replace('  ', '')


>>> string = " yes   Maybe   So"
>>> stripped(string)
>>>
```

Note however `string` will not be modified, You need to return the result of `x.replace()` and assign it to `string`:

```
>>> def stripped(x):
    return x.replace('  ', '')

>>> string = " yes   Maybe   So"
>>> string = stripped(string)
>>> string
' yes Maybe So'
>>>
```

Note what your asking for is *techinally* possible. **It is a monkey-patch however and shouldn't be used**. But just for completeness:

```
>>> _str = str
>>> 
>>> class str(_str):
    def stripped(self):
        return self.replace('  ', '')


>>> string = str(" yes   Maybe   So")
>>> string.stripped()
' yes Maybe So'
>>>
```

Comment: Gotcha I didnt think I would have to return it, I wasnt understanding that properly, thanks for the help this works. I will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: @Cannon Glad I could help .

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a method to an existing class like that. You could write a function that receives and returns a string:

```
def stripped(x):
    return x.replace('  ', '')
```

And the call it by passing your string:

```
s = " yes   Maybe   So"
s = stripped(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want all whitespace, not just spaces, you can do `''.join(string.split())`

```
def stripped(string):
    return ''.join(string.split())

string = stripped(' yes   Maybe   So')

# But it would also handle this
string = stripped(' yes \n Maybe  So\n')
assert string == 'yesMaybeSo'
```

Comment: While this does perhaps offer a better method, it doesn't answer the main question, which is probably why you got downvoted. (I didn't downvote).