# why is it better to overload comparison operators as == outside the class

Tags: c++, operators, overloading, getter, friend-function

I'm trying to understand why are comparison operators are overloaded as an outside function:

```
class Test {
  // private fields
 public:
  // methods
  friend bool operator==(cons Test & t1, const Test & t2);
};

bool operator==(cons Test & t1, const Test & t2){
  return (t1.fields==t2.fields);
}
```

rather than implement it inside the class:

```
class Test {
  // private fields
public:
  // methods
  bool operator==(const Test & other){
    return (this.fields==other.fields);
  }
};
```

what other considerations can I use when deciding whether to overload an operator inside the class or outside it. when is it better to use fried? and when will i prefer using getters?

or perhaps a helper function to pass me private fields such as:

```
class Test {
  // private fields
public:
  // methods
  ostream& print()(ostream& os){
    os << this.private_field;
    return os;
  }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Test& t) {
  return t.print(os);
}
```

Comment: I suspect you may need to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028773/free-function-versus-member-function