# Container contains function?

Tags: c++, containers

Sometimes I want check if a std::unordered_map container contains an element, that's all I want to know, I don't want an iterator, I don't want to check the iterator against end(). Say for std::unordered_map<int, int>:

```
if (mymap.contains(5)) // Do something;
```

Instead of:

```
auto it = mymap.find(5);
if (it != mymap.end()) Do something;
```

What's the best way to have this?

Comment: Use [C++ 20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains)?

Comment: But why? In the case you check, find the need of further processing, you have AGAIN to get the iterators. Operate via `contains` or `count` comes with a cost!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ designers have finally caught on to the fact that this is such a common operation, and have kindly added [`std::unordered_map::contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains) to the language in C++20.

If you can't use C++20 yet, you can always write your own implementation as a free function:

```cpp
template<typename M, typename T>
bool contains(M const &map, T const &element) {
  return map.find(element) != map.end();
}
```

Comment: Who pushed this through committee? Not all heroes wear capes!

Answer (score 1):

`std::unordered_map` supports [`contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains) since C++20.

```
bool contains( const Key& key ) const;
template< class K > bool contains( const K& x ) const;
```

Before C++20 you can use [`count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/count), e.g.

```
if (mymap.count(5) == 1) // Do something;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before C++20 you can use [`std::unordered_map::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/count):

```
if (mymap.count(5)) // Do something;
```

Some like to be explicit and write

```
if (mymap.count(5) == 1)
```

though thats a matter of style and it appears that you want to avoid an explicit comparison.

Note that a map either contains the key or not, so despite its name `count` does not really "count". The result is either `0` or `1`.

Since C++20 there is `std::unodered_map::contains` that returns a `bool`.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to just creating your own class, inheriting from std::unordered map and adding extra functions?

Comment: @Zebrafish publicly inheriting from std containers isnt a good idea, their destructor isnt virtual. If you inherit privately, you would need to forward the complete interface. In general free functions are prefered over member function when possible (have to look for a reference...)

Comment: @Zebrafish https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028773/free-function-versus-member-function I would rather go for a  `bool contains( std::unodered_map, KeyType)` as suggested in the other answer