# Using find() in a simple std::map derived class: can not explain compile error

Tags: c++

I'm using quite often simple map lookup, where I want to avoid exception handling...
Therefore I wrote first a "helper" function, then a simple derived class.
However, I can NOT explain the compile error when using "find()" (and "end()") directly (1); it works when using "this->" (2) or "map<K, T>::" (3).
Can anyone explain?

I hope the code/intention is clear enough.

Thanks,
Gabriel

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


//convenient helper
template <typename K, typename T> class map_ex: public map<K, T>
{
public:
  bool try_get(const K k, T &v)
  {
    auto f = find(k); //1: not found ??!
    //auto f = this->find(k); //2: works
    //auto f = map<K, T>::find(k); //3: works
    bool found = f != this->end();
    if(found) v = f->second;
    return found;
  };
};

int main()
{
    map_ex<string, string> m;
    m["test"] = "1";
    string v;
    m.try_get("test", v);
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dependent name -> `this->find(k)`.

Comment: btw you do not need inheritance. The same functionalitly can be supplied via a free function (while inheriting from `std::map` is dangerous, you arent doing it in your code, but it can be easily used wrong)

Comment: ok, now I understand.
@463035818_is_not_a_number I have used first a free function, but I just wanted to have an "OO look" :)

Comment: what is an "OO look" ? Placing everything inside a class is a "terrible look", its not what object orientation is about

Comment: In my (subjective) opinion,  `m.try_get("test", v)` looks nicer than `try_get(m, "test", v)`

Comment: your (subjective) opinion is against a common recommendation to use free functions when possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028773/free-function-versus-member-function and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989734/effective-c-item-23-prefer-non-member-non-friend-functions-to-member-functions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967538/c-member-functions-vs-free-functions?rq=1